# Unable to click on a button using Content-desc in appium

Tags: android, appium, android-uiautomator

I'm new to testing in Appium. I was able to set everything up and to run the test. I used UiAutomatorViewer to get access to some Buttons, now I need to Click on a Button, but I just got the Cont-desc. I tried the following XPaths but I ended up getting an error. Any Help would be nice.

1. @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@contentDescription='SIGN IN     log in ']")
2. driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//android.widget.Button[@content-desc='SIGN IN     log in ']")).Click();
3. driver.FindElement(By.Name('SIGN IN     log in ')).Click();
4. driver.FindElement(By.Xpath(//*[@Class='android.view.View' OR @content-desc='SIGN IN     log in '])).Click();

Thank you[image] in advance :)

Comment: What about clicking the one above one level ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following `xpath`:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@content-desc, 'SIGN')]")).Click();
```